# Image not showing in RecyclerView using api data Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview

This is my code in which the image is not showing properly:

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.PhotoViewHolder> implements SizeCalculatorDelegate {


    ArrayList<String> source_title = new ArrayList<String>();


    private final double[] mImageAspectRatios;


    private Context mContext;


    public double aspectRatioForIndex(int index) {
        // Precaution, have better handling for this in greedo-layout
        if (index >= getItemCount()) return 1.0;


        return mImageAspectRatios[getLoopedIndex(index)];
    }

    public class PhotoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView mImageView;

        public PhotoViewHolder(ImageView imageView) {
            super(imageView);
            mImageView = imageView;

        }
    }

    public MoviesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> image) {
        mContext = context;
        this.source_title = image;

        mImageAspectRatios = new double[source_title.size()];
//        calculateImageAspectRatios();
    }

    @Override
    public PhotoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        ));
        return new PhotoViewHolder(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PhotoViewHolder holder, int position) {


 Picasso.with(mContext).load(source_title.get(position)).into(new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                int width = bitmap.getWidth();
                int height = bitmap.getHeight();
                holder.mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                Log.d("bitmapfailed", "errorDrawable " + errorDrawable);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                Log.d("onPrepareLoad", "placeHolderDrawable " + placeHolderDrawable);
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return source_title.size();
    }

//    private void calculateImageAspectRatios() {
//        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
//
//        for (int i = 0; i < source_title.size(); i++) {
//
//            int value = Integer.parseInt(source_title.get(i));
//
//            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), value, options);
//            mImageAspectRatios[i] = options.outWidth / (double) options.outHeight;
//        }
//    }

    // Index gets wrapped around <code>Constants.IMAGES.length</code> so we can loop content.
    private int getLoopedIndex(int index) {
        return index % source_title.size(); // wrap around
    }
}
```

and this is the original demo code

```
public class PhotosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotosAdapter.PhotoViewHolder> implements SizeCalculatorDelegate {
    private static final int IMAGE_COUNT = 500; // number of images adapter will show

    private final int[] mImageResIds = Constants.IMAGES;
    private final double[] mImageAspectRatios = new double[mImageResIds.length];


    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public double aspectRatioForIndex(int index) {
        // Precaution, have better handling for this in greedo-layout
        if (index >= getItemCount()) return 1.0;

        Log.d("index", mImageAspectRatios + "");

        return mImageAspectRatios[getLoopedIndex(index)];
    }

    public class PhotoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView mImageView;

        public PhotoViewHolder(ImageView imageView) {
            super(imageView);
            mImageView = imageView;

        }
    }

    public PhotosAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        calculateImageAspectRatios();
    }

    @Override
    public PhotoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        ));
        return new PhotoViewHolder(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PhotoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(mImageResIds[getLoopedIndex(position)])
                .into(holder.mImageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return IMAGE_COUNT;
    }

    private void calculateImageAspectRatios() {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < mImageResIds.length; i++) {
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), mImageResIds[i], options);
            mImageAspectRatios[i] = options.outWidth / (double) options.outHeight;
        }
    }

    // Index gets wrapped around <code>Constants.IMAGES.length</code> so we can loop content.
    private int getLoopedIndex(int index) {
        return index % Constants.IMAGES.length; // wrap around
    }
}
```

in this demo the image shows properly but in my demo images not show, tha data from source_title arraylist is showing properly but this demo does not work properly, as I use onBindViewHolder method it goes into onPrepareLoad exception called null value of placeHolderDrawable...

Is there any solution to use it or some other method or way to solve this issue?
Sorry for my english and thnx in advance...

Comment: try with this line Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).resize(90, 90).into(holder.profilePic);

Comment: Thnx for your responce but not working at all...

Comment: is the image available on server?

Comment: yes sir all url has a image in it

Comment: did you already check each image url is exists or not in browser? it may be spacing problem or the size of image is too large to display..

Comment: i have to take the original size of image for my app image , its large or small not matter for this app...

Comment: can you share any iamge url which you are trying to show in your app

Comment: https://static.picsdream.com/media/h265/2016/04/1476120622_DrHQQL5KHB14RUTiyK1p.jpg

Comment: u geeting my Point?